# Android how to save simple data

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to save a simple data (example for settings) in an android application.

How can this be possible (I want to use something like cookies in javascript)?

Comment: How about this link: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).